# Check if a date is before or equal php

Tags: php

I am trying to check if a date is before or equal to the date on the Server and having trouble currently.

This is my code:

```
<td>
    @if(strtotime($winner->win_date) <= date('Y-m-d'))
        Valid
    @else
        Expired
    @endif
</td>
```

The winners date is : 2014-09-11 I want to check if it before or equal to todays date

Comment: strtotime($winner->win_date) <= strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` returns a UNIX timestamp, which you'll want to compare to a UNIX timestamp:

```
@if (strtotime($winner->win_date) <= time())
```

Answer (score 0):

try to convert both date same using `date()`

```
@if(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($winner->win_date)) <= date('Y-m-d'))
```

or convert both in timestamp

```
@if(strtotime($winner->win_date) <= strtotime(date('Y-m-d')))
```

Comment: That answer worked, I will accept it. I don't know why downvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
    <?php 
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
    $win_date = $winner->win_date;

    if(strtotime($win_date) <= strtotime($today)){
        echo "Valid";
    }else{
    echo "Expired";
    }
    ?>
</td>
```